# Python socket error - how to repair

Tags: python, sockets, error-handling, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
>>> import socket
>>> sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sck.connect(('loaclhost', 2525))
```

And I have this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
>     sck.connect(('localhost', 2526))
> socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because
> ```
>
> the target machine actively refused it

Please helpe me. Where can be error? How can I repair it?

Comment: Why are you creating two sockets and discarding one? Why does you error show a failed connection to port 2526, and you code an attempted connection to port 2525?  Is something actually listening on either of those ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and error don't match (spelling of localhost and port number), but the error message is due to no server listening on that port.  Cut and paste the exact code and error message next time.

Comment: Thanks. But why can I send string in send method?

Comment: Show actual code (cut and paste) and error for your problem.  We aren't mind readers and what you show is inconsistent.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now it works. I have used "b" before string and it works.

Answer (score 5):

try changing the connection to "localhost" instead of "loaclhost"